# Function returns selector instead of value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
var _el = $('ul').find('li');

var _id = _el.each(function() {
    var ids = {};

    $($(this).data('offer-id')).each(function() {
        if (this !== '') {
            ids[this] = this;
        }
    });
    var $id = Object.keys(id);
    var $id_ = $id.toString();

    return $id;
});
console.log(_id);
```

This returns `$id` instead of its value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you are lookig for .map() instead of .each()

Comment: what is the value of the variable `id`(`Object.keys(id)`) within the loop? - shouldn't it be `ids`

Comment: Not sure what you want to do, but the code doesn't look right. `this !== ''`?, `ids[this] = this`?, `$($(this)`?

Comment: when i use map what i get is array, i need separated strings...

Comment: can you share the html sample like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/59DTh/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/59DTh/2/ it's ok but how to split them to separated strings, not one?

Comment: Just use an array, or split your string on `,` char

Answer (score 1):

If you only intend to retrieve the values of the `data-offer-id` attribute you can just loop through the `<li>` elements with jQuery `.each()`.

The below will output ids from 1 to 6:

```
$('li').each(function() {

    console.log($(this).data('offer-id'));
});
```

If you want it in an array instead, just push the data attribute value within the loop.

The below will output `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

```
var ids = [];

$('li').each(function() {

    ids.push($(this).data('offer-id'));
});

console.log(ids);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is the goal? Get the `data-offer-id` attribute value? So, loop through the `li` elements and get the attribute.

Comment: Better than just giving working code, the best way to answer a question is to explain why the OP code is not working, and how to correct it. Just giving code with no explanation won't help him and others future readers.

Comment: @OlivierH You are right. I could have given more info. Still I see no reason that this answer got me 2 downvotes...

Comment: If you edit your answer i'll be pleased to upvote you.